# Press q to quit outputs incorrect math

Tags: c

I am trying to use "Press 'q' to quit" functionality to exit a do...while loop for calculating the average of a series of user-defined integers. Following several examples I was able to get the exit value to work but it is being included as part of calculating the average.

Example:

```
quixote@willow:~$ gcc sentinel-borked.c -o sentinel-borked
sentinel-borked.c: In function 'main':
sentinel-borked.c:22:13: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         sum = sum + value;
             ^
quixote@willow:~$ ./sentinel-borked 

Enter an answer string or q to quit: 1

Enter an answer string or q to quit: 1

Enter an answer string or q to quit: q

Count is: 3
Average is: 214197589.333333
quixote@willow:~$
```

I know that the "q" is being treated as an integer, but I'm not sure how to re-write my code to escape it. :(

The simplest workaround that I can think of is to prompt the user for an end point (i.e. "how many integers are you averaging?") and use that, but I would really like to figure this out.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
/* variable definition: */
int count, sum;
double avg;
char *value;

/* Initialize */
count = 0;
sum = 0;
avg = 0.0;

do {
// Loop through to input values
printf("\nEnter an answer string or q to quit: ");
fgets(value, 10, stdin);

    if (value >= 0){
        sum = sum + value;
        count = count + 1;
    }
    else {
            printf("\nValue must be positive");
}

} while (value[0] != 'q');

// Calculate avg. Need to type cast since two integers will yield an integer

printf("\nCount is: %d", count);
avg = (double) sum/count;
printf("\nAverage is: %lf\n", avg);


return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Replaced screenshot with plain-text inside of a code block. Original image still located at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qza1N.png

Comment: `value` is not allocated.

Comment: next error: `fgets(value, 10, stdin);

    if (value >= 0){` `value` is a string, not a number... compile with warnings on.

Comment: `error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]: sum = sum + value;`

Comment: You incorrectly assume that C automatically casts a string to a number when necessary, like some script languages do. This is not the case. Instead, C somehow mangles the address of the string to an integer - implementation-defined behaviour, result depends on the compiler.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings and do not ignore them.

Comment: DonT' post images of text! And enable compiler warnings! A good text book is a way better resource to learn than obscure online tutorial or youtube!

Comment: Incredibly, there is a compiler warning at the top of your screenshot. Should get your eyes tested.

Comment: @WeatherVane I heard there is a cognitive disorder, making the *warning* prefix to make things invisible.

Comment: ... but as the compiler did not warn about the *uninitialised variable* you should either up the warning level, or bin the compiler.

Comment: Are the downvotes just because op provided a screenshot? Because he provides an optimum code and a clear problem.

Comment: My apologies, first I felt as though the screenshot provided a clearer visual of the output that using [code] tags would not. Will Try Harder next time.

Secondly, I was not ignoring the compiler warnings, I did state that I knew that "q" was being treated as an INT and not a Char but was hoping to kill two birds with one stone... i.e get the program to read INT's properly while accepting strings/characters for the exit function. 

If I were writing this code for a production environment I would do a lot of things differently :) Right now the goal is simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
/* variable definition: */
    int count, sum;

    double avg=0;

    char value[10]="";//make value an array or allocate memory for it using malloc and also null initiate it


/* Initialize */
    count = 0;

    sum = 0;

    avg = 0.0;

    fgets(value,10,stdin);

    if(value[strlen(value)-1]=='\n'){//if the user enters a string less than 10 chars a newline will also be stored inside the value array

        value[strlen(value)-1]='\0';//you need to remove that \n and replace it with null
    }

    else{

        while((getchar())!='\n');//just removing any extra chars left(when the user enters a string greater than 10 chars)
    }

    while(value[0]!='q'){//beware it will only check for the first char of the array to be q, anything else will still proceed the loop

        sum+=strtol(value,NULL,10);//use this to convert integers inside the array to long ints(many other ways exists)

        count++;

        fgets(value,10,stdin);//overwrite value each time to get input

        if(value[strlen(value)-1]=='\n'){

            value[strlen(value)-1]='\0';
        }

        else{

            while((getchar())!='\n');
        }

    }



// Calculate avg. Need to type cast since two integers will yield an integer

    printf("\nCount is: %d", count);

    if(count==0){
        printf("\nAverage is: %lf\n", avg);
    }
    else{
         avg = (double) sum/count;

         printf("\nAverage is: %lf\n", avg);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not tested this code, but should work. Poke me instead!

Comment: I have explained the code in the comments within the code :) @Jean-Baptiste Yunes

Comment: @VidorVistrom -- That works! :D It is considerably more complex than I was thinking it -should- be but I'm used to Bash and Python ways of doing things ;). Now just need to understand what and why. 

Before anyone else comments about this... I DID see the implicit function warning and chose to ignore it in favor of fixing it later